# Why does the first and last value in my code's output doubles?

Tags: c++

```
int i = 0;
int e = 0;

cin >> i >> e;

    cout << i;
    while( ++i <= e ) {
    cout << "." << i;
    }

    while ( --i >= e ){
        cout << '.' << i;
    }
```

hello everyone, can I ask for some help regarding this.
If I run my code and if I input for example:

INPUT: 1 5

MY CODE OUTPUTS: 1.2.3.4.5.5

INPUT: 5
1

MY CODE OUTPUTS: 5.5.4.3.2.1

The output should be;

INPUT: 1
5

OUTPUT SHOULD BE: 1.2.3.4.5

INPUT: 5 1

OUTPUT SHOULD BE: 5.4.3.2.1

Comment: Stepping through the program in a debugger would give you your answer in under a minute. Might take a bit longer to figure out a good fix, but you'd probably have that before anyone could write decent answer.

Comment: The second loop is executed once... as the previous answere tells you: use an debugger and set the breakpoints well, you will see it very quick... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's discuss the first input: 1 5. When you're reaching 5 by **pre-incrementing** the i, it prints the value of i which is 5. then it comes back to while loop again first increments the value of i (which gets to 6) then it checks the condition where **6<=e** is false so the loop breaks.

Then it goes to the second loop. **it decreases the value first** and make the value of **i=5** and checks if **i>=e** which is true so it prints the i. after the first iteration value of i becomes less then e so it doesn't print anything after that.

Comment: what should I do to fix it?

Comment: you can use two conditions for these two scenarios. if i<=e, use first while loop else use second while loop. Same approach was suggested above by selbie

Answer (score 2):

Here's a strong hint:

```
cin >> i >> e;

if (i <= e) {
    // your code to print everything from i up to e goes here
}
else {
    // your code to print everything from e down to i goes here
}
```

Trying to run the two while loops with prefix increment/decrement operators is just asking for bugs.

Comment: if I remove the increment and decrement and change it only to I, it outputs infinitely.

Comment: I'm suggesting you start over. Past the sample code I offered above.  And then you insert a different `for` loop for both conditions.  Do you know how a for loop works?

Comment: no, I'm self-studying about programming, my course is really nursing, but I really just want to learn to program.

Answer (score 0):

In your 1st while loop, even if it doesnot gets executed, the `++i <= e` will get evaluated and the value of i will increment.

Suppose if the input is

> 1 5

The output after the first while loop will be

> 1.2.3.4.5

At this position the value of i is 6, because when i became 5, then again the expression `++i <= e` will be evaluated and i will get incremented resulting in `i=6`

Now moving to 2nd while loop,

As `--i = 5`, which is `>=5 (as e=5)`
So loop gets executed and prints 5 one more time.

To fix this just decrement value of i by 1, after the first while loop, and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Let's discuss the first input: 1 5. When you're reaching 5 by **pre-incrementing** the i, it prints the value of i which is 5. then it comes back to while loop again first increments the value of i (which gets to 6) then it checks the condition where **6<=e** is false so the loop breaks.

Then it goes to the second loop. **it decreases the value first** and make the value of **i=5** and checks if **i>=e** which is true so it prints the i. after the first iteration value of i becomes less then e so it doesn't print anything after that.